# Distributed YARN or Mesos container

Tags: hadoop-yarn, mesos

Is there a way I can add the PIDs of two processes running in separate physical nodes (of the same cluster) to the same YARN/Mesos container?

Comment: do you mean run tasks in different machines?

Comment: You should consider accepting answers given to your questions or explain why the given answers do not solve the problems -- looking at your profile hints there is room for improvement.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that by YARN/Mesos Container you mean Docker Container. 
In that case no, as a single docker container is tied a specific host.
The usual idea with YARN/Mesos is to compose your application/framework out of several tasks (which could mean several container) which then can be scheduled across several nodes.

So the answer would be that you cannot combine processes on different hosts to the same container, but one application on YARN/Mesos can consist of several containers running on separate physical machines. See for example [Mesos architecture](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/mesos-architecture/).

I hope this helped clarify the picture, otherwise please explain in more detail what you want to achieve.